# how to run a table multiple times in BIRT report

Tags: javascript, mysql, dataset, grouping, birt

I have a data set which returns 7 columns(product name , net pay, difference, ..).I need to pick top 5 rows for each products on the basis of net_pay.
for example there are 4 products like car , air, bus and rail and  for each product there are 10 rows so i need top 5 rows for each product on the basis of net_pay i.e for car top 5 rows ,air top 5 rows,bus top 5 rows &rail top 5 rows.
how to handle this ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but the idea is to add a group to the table. The group is based on the product column.
The top-5 can be done with Is-Top-N in BIRT.
On an Oracle DB this could be done with SQL.

Comment: thank you for your reply I already made a way to solve this problem. And it  is working fine